# Can I reuse the downloaded files from the VS2010 web installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed VS2010 pro using the web installer, but now need to install it on another machine. As this new install will require the same features as my current install, is it possible to reuse the files already downloaded? And if so, how is this achieved?

Comment: Have you been able to find where the files are downloaded to? Is it a temporary directory name, or something that looks somewhat standard?

Comment: Isn't SuperUser the right place for this question?

Comment: @ramon, perhaps SuperUser would be an appropriate place for this question, but I certainly see lots of questions regarding Visual Studio usage on Stack Overflow. Do you have a link to some guidelines that indicate SuperUser is a superior location for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You might find some tips here. This is for the older VS web installer for the express editions, but perhaps the concepts are the same.

http://vicker313.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/how-to-offline-install-visual-studio-express-without-download-the-whole-image-file/

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, the setup uses files from

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local settings\Temp\30319.01\1033\VS_VSTD
```

but I don't yet know how to reuse them, or if that directory is the result of unpacking files from somewhere else.

I used `filemon` to see from where the setup was reading and writing.